# R Error "Error in element_line(colour = text_and_line_color, linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 1, : unused argument (linewidth = 0.5)"

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-package

I'm using the interactions package in R and keep getting an error when running the plotting functions (cat_plot, interact_plot). It seems like it may be an issue with a ggplot2 update, but I don't know enough to be able to resolve that.

I get the same error when I run the example code provided by the R documentation so I'll include that:

```
library(interactions)
data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")
mpg2 <- mpg
mpg2$auto <- "auto"
mpg2$auto[mpg2$trans %in% c("manual(m5)", "manual(m6)")] <- "manual"
mpg2$auto <- factor(mpg2$auto)
mpg2$fwd <- "2wd"
mpg2$fwd[mpg2$drv == "4"] <- "4wd"
mpg2$fwd <- factor(mpg2$fwd)
## Drop the two cars with 5 cylinders (rest are 4, 6, or 8)
mpg2 <- mpg2[mpg2$cyl != "5",]
mpg2$cyl <- factor(mpg2$cyl)
## Fit the model
fit3 <- lm(cty ~ cyl * fwd * auto, data = mpg2)

# The line geom looks good for an ordered factor predictor
cat_plot(fit3, pred = cyl, modx = fwd, mod2 = auto, geom = "line",
 interval = TRUE)
```

cat_plot should return a plot of the model ouptut, but instead I get this error message:
Error in element_line(colour = text_and_line_color, linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 1,  :
unused argument (linewidth = 0.5)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine using `interactions 1.1.5` and `ggplot2 3.4.1`. `linewidth` was introduced with ggplot2 3.4.0. Hence, try with updating `ggplot2`.

Comment: An easy fix that I didn't think of. That worked. Thanks!!